# C# MVC HTTP Sever CORS Response Header Has Duplicate Values in IE9

Tags: .net, http, iis, model-view-controller, response

For a particular request from our mvc site,  I am noticing that the server response Header contains duplicate values in IE9:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Cache-Control: private

Content-Type: text/html

Content-Encoding: gzip

Vary: Accept-Encoding,Accept-Encoding

Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5

**X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.958 Win32NT/.NET

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.958 Win32NT/.NET

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319**

Date: Mon, 10 Jul 2014 7:03:56 GMT

Content-Length: 1800 


In Chrome However, there are no duplicates:


HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Cache-Control: private

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Vary: Accept-Encoding,Accept-Encoding

Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5

X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.958 Win32NT/.NET

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

Date: Mon, 10 Jul 2014 7:17:20 GMT

Content-Length: 900

Does anyone know why this is? We are having performance issues in IE9 and suspect this may have something to do with it? Is there any IIS setting that can be set to remove the duplicate values in the response sent to IE9?